# async.js with async / await - need help explaining why this doesn't work

Tags: node.js, async-await, async.js

I am currently using async.js v2.3.0 with ES2017 async support.

I'm trying to figure out why the function `doSomething` which returns a promise works in the IIEF but `doSomething2` isn't respected. Is it because `doSoomething2` is an async function but isn't exactly running "async" code? I feel like I'm missing something here.

```
function promiseTimeOut() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     resolve(20);
   }, 1000);
 })
}

function doSomething() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   async.retry({
     times: 5,
     interval:(retryCount)=>{ return 50 * Math.pow(2, retryCount); }
   }, async () => {
     return await promiseTimeOut();
   }, (err, result) => {
     resolve(result);
   });
 })
}

async function doSomething2() {
 async.retry({
   times: 5,
   interval:(retryCount)=>{ return 50 * Math.pow(2, retryCount); }
 }, async () => {
   return await promiseTimeOut();
 }, (err, result) => {
   return result;
 });
}

// main function
(async () => {
 async.series([
   (callback) => {
     callback(null, 1);
   }, 
   async () => {
     return await doSomething();
   },
   async () => {
     // doesn't get waited on, returns undefined right away
     return await doSomething2();
   }
 ], (err, result) => {
   // result: 1, 20, undefined
   console.log(result);
 });
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing async.retry in callback style, so that it won't wait until it finished. Try to `console.log(result)`, you could see

```
[ 1, 20, undefined ]
20
```

Look at the doc for [`retry`](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#retry), as well as other method, it cited that

> Returns:
> a promise if no callback provided

So you just have to immediately return without provide any callback

```
async function doSomething2() {
  return async.retry(
    {
      times: 5,
      interval: (retryCount) => {
        return 50 * Math.pow(2, retryCount)
      },
    },
    async () => {
      return await promiseTimeOut()
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. Async.js v2.3.0 still only supports callbacks so I suspect I'll have to wrap it in a promise to get it to work. However, in Async.js v3+, a promise will be returned if no call back is given. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Async.js is performing decompilation on your code to adapt its behavior depending if you are using async function (that return promises) or callback-based functions. That's why you can see a different behavior, it simply depends on the simple fact of having an "async" keyword or not in front of your function (even if the behavior *should* be the same).

Frankly that's not a very good idea. Async.js is not bad at what is does but is clearly a library that was built to ease the use of callbacks and that was later upgraded to try to work with promises. Unfortunately that kind of auto-magic behavior based on decompilation can and will cause problems. As example it can make the code behave completely differently depending on if you're using a precompiler like Babel or not.

I recently published a library which is an alternative to async.js and that was precisely made to use only Promises (and async/await), thus making a fully-consistant library to work using those newer tools.

The result is named modern-async and is here: https://nicolas-van.github.io/modern-async/